# nontrivial intersection homology of affine vatiety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology

It is known that intersection cohomology is not homotopy invariant. Is there any example of conical  affine variety $X$ inside some varieties such that its $\text{IH}^*(X,\mathbb{Q})$ is not isomorphic to $\text{IH}^*(pt)$?

Comment: For smooth affine varieties intersection homology should just be ordinary (maybe Borel-Moore?) homology, so take for example $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$.

Comment: oh right. it is smooth

Comment: I modified the question a little bit now